# Cufon hover issue when mousing over the cufon canvas tag

Tags: css, canvas, hover, cufon

I'm trying to implement a different color / text-shadow on a standard anchor element.  While it works fine for the most part, if the mouse enters and then leaves the "cufon canvas" created element, the correct "original" properties are not re-applied... [this occurs in **FF4**]  It's hard to explain... Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLxAEZl1tqQ) showing the issue I'm encountering.

Here's the Cufon replace:

```
Cufon.replace(
    'li.haschild ul li a', {
        textShadow: '#000000 -1px -1px 1px',
        hover: {
            textShadow: '#ffffff 1px 1px 1px',
            color: '#434337'
        }
    }
);
```

So when the hover occurs, it should have a different font-color and text-shadow.  This works, as long as the mouse does not enter the portion of the anchor tag where the cufon canvas tag is.  As soon as the mouse enters that canvas tag, the Cufon hover element stops working once the mouse leaves that portion of the anchor element.  Even though the mouse is still within the anchor, and the a:hover properties are still being applied from the CSS, the cufon canvas acts differently.

I try to highlight the different elements using firebug.  The anchor tag is the element with the large amount of padding (purple).  Followed by the individual cufon canvas tags being shown.

I am not replacing an already replaced element with cufon.  If you remove the line shown above, cufon does not apply to the drop down.

I have not been able to replicate this issue on other cufon hover replaces with similar options, nor can I replicate it in **webkit** browsers.

I'm at a loss...

Comment: Unless someone has prior knowledge about this problem (or can be bothered to set up their own test case), I think we'll need to see your live site (or a test case demonstrating the problem).

Comment: There is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLxAEZl1tqQ) that I linked to above showing the problem.

Comment: Yes, I saw the video - it's *very* useful at showing the problem, but evidently nobody who looked at your question knows how to solve it off the bat. If you could link to your site or a test case, I could try some ideas out. Maybe even something stupid like sticking a load of spaces after your text would work, or a well placed `display: block` - I just don't know without being able to try. If you *really* don't want to link to the site here, you could always send me a link in an email (check my profile).

Comment: Unfortunately it's all localhost development at the moment at the moment.

Comment: When you mouse in and then out of the "cufon canvas" portion of the element, the positioning of the inner canvas tag moves by one pixel, causing the issue seen in the video...  I believe this is how cufon handles the hover effect, but it should not be de-activating the hover state when the anchor tag is clearly still in an active hover state itself.

Comment: Without a code hands-on, there's no real chance of helping solve your problem. Can you please upload that menu and post the link?